# Django Form Returns Tuple Instead of String

Tags: python, django

I have built a web page to front my teams automation scripts, this page should return a dictionary compressed into a string from a drop down menu.

Instead of a string I am getting what I think is a tuple. I need a normal string to be returned but dont know the reason for the tuple.

Views:

```
import datetime
import json
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import auth
from home.models import ChangeLog
from health.models import FirewallInfo
from . import forms
from . import sftpadd

def ipadd_index(request):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        ipadd = forms.IPAdd()
        return render(request, 'ipadd/index.html', {'ipadd': ipadd})
    else:
        return redirect('/unauthorized/')

def ipadd_action(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.IPAdd(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            casenum = request.POST.get('casenum')
            ipaddr = request.POST.get('ipaddr')
            objgp = request.POST.get('objgp')
            cidr = request.POST.get('cidr')
            objgp = ''.join(objgp)
            objgp = json.loads(objgp)
            asa = []
            for k, v in objgp:
                OBJGP = k
                for item in v:
                    firewall = FirewallInfo.get(fw_name=item)
                    asa.append(firewall.fw_ip)
            for fw in asa:
                if cidr == 'HOST':
                    sftpadd.sftpadd_host(ipaddr, fw)
                else:
                    sftpadd.sftpadd_sub(ipaddr, cidr, fw)
                sftpadd.save(fw)
            dbdetails = str(ipaddr) + ' has been added to ' + str(OBJGP)
            dbentry = ChangeLog(
                user_name=request.user.username,
                change_date=datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                change_cr='N/A',
                change_type='IP Add',
                details=dbdetails,
                case_num=casenum)
            dbentry.save()
            item = ChangeLog.get(pk=dbentry.pk)
            return render(request, 'change/detail.html', {'item': item})
        else:
            return redirect('/Oops/')
    else:
        return redirect('/ipadd/')
```

Forms:

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class IPAdd(forms.Form):
    CIDR = [
        ('HOST', 'Host'),
        (24, '/24'),
        (25, '/25'),
        (26, '/26'),
        (27, '/27'),
        (28, '/28'),
        (29, '/29'),
        (30, '/30'),
        (31, '/31'),
    ]
    OBJGP = [
        (
            None,
            'Select',
        ),
        (
            {"EXT-SFTPALLOWED": ["IPAYDEVDMZSMO-FW", "IPAYATX-EDGE-FW", "IPAYPRODDMZBMO-FW", "IPAYDEVDMZSMO-FW"]},
            'EXT-SFTPALLOWED',
        ),
    ]
    casenum = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Case#'}),
        required=True,
        label="")
    ipaddr = forms.GenericIPAddressField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'IP Address'}),
        required=True,
        label='')
    cidr = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Type'}),
        choices=(CIDR),
        label='')
    objgp = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Type'}),
        choices=(OBJGP),
        label='')
```

html value:

```
<option value="{&#39;EXT-SFTPALLOWED&#39;: [&#39;IPAYDEVDMZSMO-FW&#39;, &#39;IPAYATX-EDGE-FW&#39;, &#39;IPAYPRODDMZBMO-FW&#39;, &#39;IPAYDEVDMZSMO-FW&#39;]}">
    EXT-SFTPALLOWED
</option>
```

POST showing tuple in "objgp":

```
casenum     '1234'
objgp       ("{'EXT-SFTPALLOWED': ['IPAYDEVDMZSMO-FW', 'IPAYATX-EDGE-FW', 'IPAYPRODDMZBMO-FW', 'IPAYDEVDMZSMO-FW']}")
csrfmiddlewaretoken     '______________________________'
ipaddr      '10.1.1.10'
cidr        'HOST'
```

Comment: The POST value for `objgp` is a string, according to the data in your question. The parethesis around it are only a tuple if there is a comma after the first element of the tuple. Without the comma (which converts it into a tuple) the parethesis do not alter the value they surround.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I see you tried to add an image into your question, but there was no link to the actual image.

Comment: Im trying to json.loads objgp to iterate through the dictionary.

Comment: ive tried everything and a half to get it to load with no luck.

Comment: I rewrote the script around the issue so its resolved but I still dont understand why i was being sent a tuple from an html form that wouldnt behave.